# Неподвижный header

Tags: php, html, css, javascript

Вопрос в принципе вот в чем, извиняюсь если назову как-то неправильно.
Нужно, что бы верхний блок header был неподвижен и пролистывался вместе со страницей. К примеру, на данный момент, если я скролю страницу вниз, то верхний блок уходит "за браузер", мне же нужно чтобы он оставался всегда на виду! В общем как на "Одноклассники" либо на "Спрашивай.ру".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position: static;background-attachment: fixed;"></div>
```